# Is there a name for this pattern in JS/TS?

Tags: javascript, typescript, oop

I have two modules which has same interfaces. Instead for implementing the business logic twice for each module, I created an `abstract` class with the implementations and also created an `abstract` method to provide the module to act on.

So, the module class will extend the base class and provide the module. Now, all the implementation will act on the provided module.

I wanted to know if this a pattern commonly followed. If so, what's the name of the pattern.

```
interface ModuleInterface {
    name?: string;
    age?: number;
}

abstract class Base {
    protected abstract provideModule(): ModuleInterface;

    getName() {
        const module = this.provideModule();
        return module.name;
    }

    getAge() {
        const module = this.provideModule();
        return module.age;
    }
}

class Person1 extends Base {
    provideModule() {
        return {
            name: 'John',
            age: 27,
        };
    }
}

class Person2 extends Base {
    provideModule() {
        return {
            name: 'Mike',
            age: 29,
        };
    }
}

const person1 = new Person1();
const person2 = new Person2();

console.log(person1.getName());
console.log(person2.getName());
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle isnt it?

Comment: Why don't you provide the module as a parameter upon creation or assign it in the constructor? You would be using basic inheritance and compostion. What design pattern you would/should be using also depends on your purpose, which isn't clear to me.